# Problems with AT command AT&W and memory storages

Tags: c#, configuration, serial-port, at-command, modem

I'im trying to understand the working with modems using at commands! I got ZTE MF667 modem and i want to be able to receive and send sms. I make the following sequence using c# class `SerialPort`

```
com = new SerialPort(port);
com.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend;
com.NewLine = System.Environment.NewLine;
com.ReadTimeout = ReadTimeout;
com.WriteTimeout = -1;
com.Open();

com.Write(@"AT+CPMS=""SM"",""SM"",""SM""\r\n");
com.Write("AT&W\r\n");
com.Write("AT+ZRST\r\n");
```

So i set the memory storage to sim card. Then i reset the modem using `zrst` command. After the modem gets reset, i send "ATZ" or "ATZ0" and after, when i verify the setting with "AT&V" the `+CPMS` is back to factory value again! Does anyone had this kind of behaviour and probably can help me? How do i make zte mf667 to save the configuration in modem memory? Also with this modem, i encountered the weird behaviour when reading the sms. It cannot be read from `"ME"` storage, even if you turn on `"CNMI"` it reports that the message received in the `"ME"` storage,always with 0 index but, the `CMGR="ALL"` for the "ME" gives 0 messages. So i have no other choice, but to switch to the sim memory!

Comment: So you set some config, then reset and lose the config? That seem logical.  Reset first, then configure.

Comment: @AlexK. but sir, isn't `AT+ZRST` is the same as if i would replug my usb modem?

Comment: Yes  so the previous commands like AT+CPMS would be wiped

Comment: @AlexK. i do not understand! So what would be the correct way? Let's say i made the `CPMS` to sim, and saved it. Then i need to re-plug my modem. I close the com port, adn re-plug my modem. The configuration that i made is lost? Does it mean that the configuration is saved only for one "session" until the modem gets unplugged?

Comment: Some devices may retain config, others not.  In this case it does not matter as you set it up then *specifically* tell it to reset itself.  You should always setup the modem as needed before you use it.

Comment: @AlexK. so it's better to just set it up all the time. I am trying to reset it because it helps to switch to the "SM" memory. If i do not reset it for some reason the modem keep reversing itself to the "ME" which is not supported by at commands. The full sequence i do is:  `ATZ` , `AT+ZSNT=0,0,0` , `AT+CMGF=1`, `AT+CPMS="SM","SM","SM"` ,`AT+CNMI=2,1`. Then if i do `AT+CUSD=1,"*102#",15` (the ussd that should give me the sms) i receive the notify  `+CMTI: "ME",0` all the time the index is zero, and the storage is "ME"! Is it possible to fix somehow not reseting the modem all the time?